# Fieldsets and Child object fields in apex

Tags: apex, fieldsets

I created a FieldSet (*Fruit_FieldSet*) in my org. Its on the object Fruit (which is the master). I added fields from the child object Apple (*Apple_Type*, which is a standard field) to the Fruit_FieldSet.

Now, I am writing a trigger on Fruit, where I created a field called *LastModified_SpecificFields*. If any of the fields in the Fruit_FieldSet are updated, the trigger on Fruit updates the field LastModified_SpecificFields with the date and time of when the update occurred!

My trigger is not working for the Apple object fields, but is working for the Fruit fields. I am giving my trigger code below. I am not sure, if I am missing something! Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

**TRIGGER HELPER CLASS**

```
    public static void specificFieldsChanged(Map<Id, Fruit__c> newFruitsMap, Map<Id, Fruit__c> oldFruitsMap){
            // Extract list of fieldnames from Fruit_FieldSet fieldset
            Set<String> fruitFieldSetFields;
            List<Schema.FieldSetMember> FruitFieldSet = Schema.SObjectType.Fruit__c.fieldSets.Fruit_FieldSet.getFields();
            if (FruitFieldSet!=null) {
                    fruitFieldSetFields = new Set<String>();
                    for (FieldSetMember fsm : FruitFieldSet) {
                           fruitFieldSetFields.add(fsm.getFieldPath());
                    }
            }

            Fruit__c fruitPriorValue;
            Set<Id> fruitIds = new Set<Id>();
            if(fruitFieldSetFields != null){
                    for(Fruit__c newFruitValue : newFruitsMap.values()){
                            fruitPriorValue = oldFruitssMap.get(newFruitValue.Id);
                            for (String fieldName : fruitFieldSetFields) {
                                    if (fruitPriorValue.get(fieldName) != newFruitValue.get(fieldName)) {
                                          newFruitValue.LastModified_SpecificFields__c = Datetime.now();
                                          break;
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

**TRIGGER**

```
    trigger Ev_FruitTrigger on Fruit__c (before update, after update, before insert) {
            if (Trigger.isBefore) {
                    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
                        Ev_FruitTriggerHandler.specificFieldsChanged(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.oldMap);
                    }
                    if (Trigger.isInsert) {
                        Ev_FruitTriggerHandler.specificFieldsChanged(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.oldMap);
                    }
            }
     }
```

Comment: I assume you are using a formula field on the Fruit object to represent the child (apple) field values?  Is this correct?  If so, then this is the issue.  A change in child field will not be detected as a change in the parent, even though the value of the formula field will change.  Formula field changes do not fire workflows or triggers.

Comment: Your trigger is running on parent (fruit). It will not be aware of any changes to children (apples) even if the update of children result in update of parent (say because of rollup summary field). You'll have to clone your trigger to detect changes on child records's fields... not sure if that's what you're after really

Comment: @eyescream: Yes, I realized that I have to create a new trigger for the child object to get its changes, which leads me to my next question: I am still referring to the Fuit_FieldSet in my Apple trigger, and I said  if(appleSpecificFields != null){                for(Apple__c newAppleValue : newAppleMap.values()){
  applePriorValue = oldApplesMap.get(newAppleValue.Id);
    for (String fieldName : appleSpecificFields) {
       if (applePriorValue.get(fieldName) != newAppleValue.get(fieldName)) {    Fruit__c. LastModified_SpecificFields__c = Datetime.now();

Comment: @eyescream: This gives me an error saying: Compile Error: Expression cannot be assigned at line -1 column -1

Comment: I think that's the one: `Fruit__c. LastModified_SpecificFields__c = Datetime.now();` - you need an object of type `Fruit__c` but you're trying to assign something to the class. It's like trying `Integer = 7` instead of `Integer i = 7`